# How does BatchNormalization work on an example?

Tags: tensorflow, machine-learning, neural-network, batch-normalization

I am trying to understand batchnorm. 
My humble example

```
layer1 = tf.keras.layers.BatchNormalization(scale=False, center=False)
x = np.array([[3.,4.]])
out = layer1(x)
print(out)
```

Prints

```
tf.Tensor([[2.99850112 3.9980015 ]], shape=(1, 2), dtype=float64)
```

My attempt to reproduce it

```
e=0.001
m = np.sum(x)/2
b = np.sum((x - m)**2)/2 
x_=(x-m)/np.sqrt(b+e)
print(x_)
```

It prints

```
[[-0.99800598  0.99800598]]
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two problems here.

First, batch norm has two "modes": Training, where normalization is done via the batch statistics, and inference, where normalization is done via "population statistics" that are collected from batches during training. Per default, keras layers/models function in inference mode, and you need to specify `training=True` in their call to change this (there are other ways, but that is the simplest one).

```
layer1 = tf.keras.layers.BatchNormalization(scale=False, center=False)
x = np.array([[3.,4.]], dtype=np.float32)
out = layer1(x, training=True)
print(out)
```

This prints `tf.Tensor([[0. 0.]], shape=(1, 2), dtype=float32)`. Still not right!

Second, batch norm normalizes over the batch axis, separately for each feature. However, the way you specify the input (as a 1x2 array) is basically a single input (batch size 1) with two features. Batch norm just normalizes each feature to mean 0 (standard deviation is not defined). Instead, you want two inputs with a single feature:

```
layer1 = tf.keras.layers.BatchNormalization(scale=False, center=False)
x = np.array([[3.],[4.]], dtype=np.float32)
out = layer1(x, training=True)
print(out)
```

This prints

```
tf.Tensor(
[[-0.99800634]
 [ 0.99800587]], shape=(2, 1), dtype=float32)
```

Alternatively, specify the "feature axis":

```
layer1 = tf.keras.layers.BatchNormalization(axis=0, scale=False, center=False)
x = np.array([[3.,4.]], dtype=np.float32)
out = layer1(x, training=True)
print(out)
```

Note that the input shape is "wrong", but we told batchnorm that axis 0 is the feature axis (it defaults to -1, the last axis). This will also give the desired result:

```
tf.Tensor([[-0.99800634  0.99800587]], shape=(1, 2), dtype=float32)
```